# Git On A Keystick & GitHub

Tags: git, github

I took a read of a few similar questions but I have only used git for a few days and my project is moving swiftly so I need to implement the Git ASAP. Closest I saw was [This Posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389894/using-git-on-usb-stick-for-travelling-code)

I work on my code at work (On breaks OF COURSE!) which is a trailer in the middle of nowhere without internet (I'm gone 4 days a week) I then come home and push changes to GitHub and work with the other contributors.

I do not own a laptop so my home workstation stays where it is and I use the company machine with a Ubuntu LiveCD and my toolchain & code on the keystick.

How would I set this up so I have the least amount of fussing around? Currently on the ubuntu machine if I do "git status" I get the error:
`fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent /media)`
`Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).`

NOTE: I currently have the latest code in GitHub for one of my projects and another project I need to initialize a new git on but I am awaiting an answer first.

Comment: Please show the contents of the keystick. Especially, verify that it has a `.git` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `git init` directly in your usb key, in order to have your git repo there, and clone that git repo on your laptop and on your company machine.

You can then:

- simply copy your plroject in that local clone, add and commit, and then push back to 'origin' (which is your usb key), making your project always saved on that key.
- add another remote called `github` and use it to push your code to GitHub when you have access to it.

You might want, [as mentioned here](http://www.totalannihilationclojurechallenge.com/2012/05/setting-gitdiscoveryacrossfilesystem.html), to set `GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM`:

```
 sudo nano /etc/environment
```

> add the following line:

```
 GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1
```

http://www.totalannihilationclojurechallenge.com/2012/05/setting-gitdiscoveryacrossfilesystem.html

Comment: I can not git clone to the local machine as its a LiveCD. I want the only local repo the exist on the keystick and only ever there. (Its USB3 so its plenty fast)

I have a project with remotes for github set up but it keeps orphaning the local master and when i do "git push origin master" and check the github site 50% of the time the commit isn't listed.

Comment: @uMinded no need to clone to clone, then, you can modify your project directly on the usb key. Don't forget to set the upstream branch when pushing to GitHub: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/git-why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time