# Is it possible for git to use my removable disk as its storing place?

Tags: git

I have a total of 3TB files, and I am looking for a way to use my removable hard drive to store these data with version control. It would be great if it can be handled in `git` way. Is this possible and how to set it up?

PS: What would be the basic size requirement of this hard drive? Is 4TB enough? Ubuntu here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389894/using-git-on-usb-stick-for-travelling-code) and also [there is no limit on git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230721/git-what-is-its-max-file-size-and-max-repository-size-limit).

> What would be the basic size requirement of this hard drive?

The removable disk needs only to have as much space as the git repository is big but more is of course always better in case you're going to expand the repository.

> how to set it up?

As long as there is a .git folder on the disk, git can handle it and it won't be able to tell whether it's operating on a local disk or a removable disk.

Why would you want to bring all of the 3TB+ under version control though?

Comment: You mean keep 3TB under version control would be too expensive (time consuming)?

Comment: I mean it's very unusual to have such a large repository. The biggest one I have **ever** heard of is facebook's, which is [54GB](https://twitter.com/feross/status/459259593630433280) and that is already absurdly large. However it's up to you what you do with and store in your repository ;-)

Comment: Go easy on me :), I am doing numerical simulations, I have two local workstations on two offices (international), and I have also several remote HPC resources (clusters from different organizations), I need constantly synchronized them between different local workstations and remote front-ends. Using ftp sometimes would cause error due to human mistakes. And besides, I would also divide this 3TB into many small repositories. Anyway, perhaps I am in the wrong way, but I think a simple backup and traveling with that big removable disk is not very ideal.

Comment: @Daniel I didn't meant to say you should use the method described in the first link I mentioned, that was just to let you know it's possible to put a git repository on a removable disk. And yeah splitting it into multiple smaller repositories sounds much better :-)

Comment: rsync may be a good solution if you only need syncronisation and not version control.

Comment: +1 for @keltar.  This doesn't sound like a version control consideration, but a synchronisation concern.

Comment: Thank you all, I will go with rsync