# How to git bundle a complete repo

Tags: git

I need to transfer a complete repo to a new non-networked machine, preferable as a single file entity. The git bundle allows a `git fetch`, `git pull` style operation in a sneakernet environment but appears to assume that you already have a working version of the repo on the destination machine.

What is the right invocation to:

1. Bundle *all* the branches in the current repo
2. Start up the new repo on the destination directory, i.e. get the root commit correctly installed

---

I've sent a patch upstream to clarify:

```
`git clone` can use any bundle created without negative refspecs
(e.g., `new`, but not `old..new`).
If you want to match `git clone --mirror`, which would clone other
refs such as `refs/remotes/*`, use `--all`.
If you want to provide the same set of refs that a clone directly
from the source repository would get, use `--branches --tags` for
the `<git-rev-list-args>`.
```

So `$ git bundle create repo.bundle --branches --tags` best matches cloning.

`$ git bundle create repo.bundle --all` will provide a mirror image of your source machine, including its remote refs.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

> What is the right invocation to:
>
> - Bundle all the branches in the current repo

Simple:

```
$ git bundle create repo.bundle --all
```

Here `repo.bundle` is the name of bundle file you want to create.  Note that `--all` would not include remote-tracking branches... just like ordinary clone wouldn't either.

> - Start up the new repo on the destination directory, i.e. get the root commit correctly installed

First, `clone` is just `init` + `fetch` (+ administrativia).

Second, you can use bundle file everywhere the repository URL can be used, so you can simply `clone` from a bundle file:

```
$ git clone repo.bundle
```

This would create `repo` as a git repository.

Comment: Thanks, the `--all` options isn't in my man page for `bundle` (I'm looking at version 1.7.6.msysgit.0), nor is the use of the .bundle file in the URLs section for `clone`. It gives me greater confidence to recommend its use.

Comment: The synopsis for **create** command is `git bundle create <file> <git-rev-list-args>`.  Running `man git-rev-list` (or `man git-log`) would give you `--all`.  But I agree that it should be more visible in the bundle command documentation.

Comment: I see that the bundle man page, under Specifying References, says that it "will only package refs that are shown by `git show-ref`", which doesn't include [list] the git-rev-list options.

Comment: @Philip Oakley: The `git-rev-list-args` is how you *select* refs that are shown by `git show-ref` command.

Comment: `--all` did include remote-tracking branches for me (git 2.1.4). I could see `refs/remotes/origin/*` with `git bundle list-heads bundlefile` or `git ls-remote bundlefile`. Although getting them back from the bundle is little tricky.

Comment: @Alex, how did you do it though? I can see the branches with your method and i can checkout the commits but i have not found a way to checkout the branches themselves.

Comment: @user3637541 I never did it. I just know that they are stored in the bundle and can be reconstructed with some script. Still missing in the bundle file is the remotes. You have a `refs/remotes/origin/master` in the bundle but the `origin` URL is lost. This is exactly why I just tar xz my _minified_ git repos instead of bundling them -- to preserve the remotes.

Comment: can any one tell me how to `bundle` only the `last 3 commits` ?

Comment: @Ben.Bean: you can `bundle` the last 3 commits in the same way as you would list them (with `git log`), for example with `git bundle create last-3-commits.bundle -3 master HEAD` (or something like that), or `master~3..master`, etc.

Comment: @JakubNarębski, I tried your command like `git bundle create latest.bundle -3 develop HEAD`, it created file as `latest.bundle` but when i tried to unbundle it using `git clone latest.undle` its throwing errors
 `Cloning into 'last-3-commits'...

 error: Repository lacks these prerequisite commits:

error: 3f2d2d3647de90fdfaed5a604473d9cabce78aa2 
error: 31921433b6c52ed2ae87a9e8cedacc22bc97b170 
fatal: bad object d1f94ed93b2df5a133118bf9f851adb6baa95911
fatal: remote did not send all necessary objects
`

Comment: @Ben.Bean: this simply means that last 3 commits are not enough - you need more than that. Simplest thing would be to check the date of latest commit in the repository you want to unbundle in, and pack `--since` that date (with some slack, just in case).

Comment: @PhilipOakley funny that [it still isn't](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/git-bundle.1.html) seven years later. But then, `git-fast-export` also mentions `--all` in the examples but doesn't mention it in the section where arguments are discussed ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L I tried to send in a doc patch but it was rejected as somehow obvious or bad https://public-inbox.org/git/7vzk4mj38g.fsf@alter.siamese.dyndns.org/

Comment: @PhilipOakley I lack the words (and not just because I am not a native speaker of English) ... thanks for the update.

Comment: How can I prevent it from messing up references? For instance, `refs/heads/4.1` is changed to `refs/remotes/origin/4.1`, and some other references are simply dropped.

Comment: OK, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48391271/3782797 gives the solution (the issue is actually when "restoring" the repository from the bundle, not creating the bundle): `git init .`, then `git fetch --update-head-ok /path/to/bundle '*:*'`. I've checked that the output of `git log --all --date=iso-local -m --name-status --decorate=full --graph --date-order` is the same.

Answer (score 49):

First clone the repository, and include the `--mirror` option.

`git clone --mirror git@example.org:path/repo.git`

This ensures all remote branched are also local branches ready for bundeling.

Then run

`git bundle create repo.bundle --all` as described by the answer from Jakub Narębski

Comment: not sure if it's just me, but after running `git bundle create --all` - the submodules aren't there

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you tar or zip the .git folder and simply unpack it in the new location and then do `git reset --hard HEAD`. Everything required for all the branches is under .git and all you should need to do is adjust any remotes in the .git/config file or remove them.

```
tar cf myrepo.tgz .git
cp myrepo.tgz [USB_STICK]
... move to new machine ...
mkdir myrepo && cd myrepo
tar xpf [USB_STICK]/myrepo.tgz
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: One caveat is that you'll need to look at the .git/config file to check if the original repo owner had any user specific stuff in there.

Comment: @patthoyts: Given that it's disconnected, there'd be no remotes ;-) It does look like bundle is (may be) missing an option, and maybe clone (need to think about cloning from a bundle)

Answer (score 4):

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), `git bundle create` is further clarified:

See [commit 1d9c8da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d9c8daef8d0c9c9f57e06eac7511c3b9355960b), [commit 0bb92f3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0bb92f3a3a0034247868b4fcd901c18654b76c4d), [commit 9ab80dd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ab80dd6aeadf398de45a6add5fc7ed6b2e166b7), [commit 5c8273d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c8273d57caf173517c9eb1ca77604709e2487b0) (31 Jul 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f19b275](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f19b2752e7788ad3a66812fd37fc482fc247eb4c), 24 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`bundle doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ab80dd6aeadf398de45a6add5fc7ed6b2e166b7): elaborate on object prerequisites
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Split out the discussion bout "object prerequisites" into its own section, and add some more examples of the common cases.
>
> See [2e0afaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e0afafebd8c5a1a8cdddb0714073461229ecfef) ("Add git-bundle: move objects and references by archive", 2007-02-22, Git v1.5.1-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77b50ab009deab7f8eb703843a71ac7253b977c8)) for the introduction of the documentation being changed here.

`git bundle` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9ab80dd6aeadf398de45a6add5fc7ed6b2e166b7/Documentation/git-bundle.txt#L156-L184):

> ### OBJECT PREREQUISITES
>
> When creating bundles it is possible to create a self-contained bundle
> that can be unbundled in a repository with no common history, as well
> as providing negative revisions to exclude objects needed in the
> earlier parts of the history.
>
> Feeding a revision such as `new` to `git bundle create` will create a
> bundle file that contains all the objects reachable from the revision
> `new`. That bundle can be unbundled in any repository to obtain a full
> history that leads to the revision `new`:
>
> ```
> $ git bundle create full.bundle new
> ```
>
> A revision range such as `old..new` will produce a bundle file that
> will require the revision `old` (and any objects reachable from it)
> to exist for the bundle to be "unbundle"-able:
>
> ```
> $ git bundle create full.bundle old..new
> ```
>
> A self-contained bundle without any prerequisites can be extracted
> into anywhere, even into an empty repository, or be cloned from
> (i.e., `new`, but not `old..new`).

`git bundle` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9ab80dd6aeadf398de45a6add5fc7ed6b2e166b7/Documentation/git-bundle.txt#L195-L198):

> The 'git bundle verify' command can be used to check whether your
> recipient repository has the required prerequisite commits for a
> bundle.