# Remove files from disk but keep Git clone directory; archive local repo

Tags: git, archive, git-clone

#### User-Story

Say I've cloned a project and pushed my work and I'm done with it for now. I expect I may need to go back to it, so I'd like to keep the clone locally to quickly switch back, but there is also a chance I am done for good, so I'd like to dump the files from disk.

#### Question

Is it possible to do this? To "archive" the local repo so I only keep the directory and `.git` dir and git understands this state when running commands like `git status`?

[EDIT:] The main reason for this question is so I can be lazy and not have to go find the repo URL to re-clone when I go back to work. This is really not a critical need but it could be pretty handy.

Comment: You can zip/tgz/whateverz the whole project directory (with the git repo) and remote the directory... you can come back later and expand the whole thing at it should be like nothing happened.

Comment: Why not just delete it entirely and re-clone it if you need it again later?

Comment: @eftshift0: That seems like the best workaround to satisfy the need

Comment: @DanielMann: See the "[EDIT]" bit I added.

Comment: With my approach, you don't have to "find the repo URL to re-clone "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tar/zip  seems to be the best workaround:

- Effectively removes the files from IDEs/search/grok. Disk wasn't really an issue but this is a lot smaller.
- Does not lose the origin URL so after unzipping there is nothing needed to begin working again, aside from pulling any updates.

[Here is a guide randomly yanked from the net.](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-compress-and-uncompress-files-and-folders-in-os-x-lion-10-7-using-terminal/)

This is just a simple workaround. If you are after something more like a backup, especially if the plan is to transfer the files, see [@VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58212586/1236083).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an archive, I would [use `git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309)

That will create *one* file, with the full repository history in it: you can easily back it up somewhere.
And you can *clone* your repository back from that one file.

You can make a script which would:

- create a bundle
- and generate a second script able to:

  - clone back that bundle
  - change the remote URL with the original Git repository "origin" URL ([`git remote get-url origin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991784/6309))

That way, you have two files to backup:

- the Git repository as a bundle
- the (generated) script able to clone *and* restore the remote origin URL once cloned from the bundle

Comment: Is this by any chance a bare repo in a tar file or similar?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not exactly: it would not include everything that a tar repo would.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Typically, local hooks would not be included (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50866035/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529039/6309)

Comment: This is pretty cool (really great for working offline if needed) but not quite there. I could write a little batch script to bundle a repo and remove the dir, but when cloning back out the origin is lost (it is set to the bundle file). The main reason for my question is so I can be lazy and not have to go find the repo URL to reclone when I go back to work ;). Any ideas? None of this is really critical. Just neat to know.

Comment: @Rafe You had selected the right answer. Once cloned back from the bundle, simply change the origin back to any remote URL you want: `git remote set-url origin https://new/url`

Comment: @Rafe I have edited the answer to address your edit about the origin URL.

Comment: The primary reason for the question is to avoid having to remember the origin URL and just go back to work. It seems like the feature doesn't exist. gzip is probably the best workaround. This is a great post but it didn't solve the core issue.

Comment: @Rafe gzip is not recommended, as it takes too much files which are specific to the original machine/can include sensitive information. It is best to have a script able to read the remote URL (See [`git remote get-url origin`]. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991784/6309), and generate 1/ a bundle, 2/ a new script able to clone that bundle and to reset the remote origin within the cloned repo, reset it to the URL that the first script has read. That way, you " avoid having to remember the origin URL ", as requested.

Comment: @VonC: I added a note to the answer that is a nod to your comment. gzip (actually tar would be what I'd use) will not contain any more sensitive info than than the repo itself. Since my original question was not related to transferring data in any way (just keeping it in place), I'm not sure this is a concern...?

Comment: @Rafe It would include possible sensitive (config) or dangerous (hooks) information, hence `git bundle`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

1. (Preferred) Delete the folder and clone again when needed. You will need to pull when you start work again anyway. There is no much benefit in storing a stale copy.
2. Keep the folder the way it is.
3. Zip the folder if you want to save space.

Comment: If #1 was preferred I wouldn't have posted this question ;). #2 isn't a solution to the question at all. #3 has some merit but again is not supported by git. It is just a workaround.

Comment: I hear you, but I'm saying it's unnecessary work and in the end you'll do a `git pull` anyway.