# Git clone : error inflate data stream error (incorrect header check)

Tags: git, clearcase

We are currently in the process of migrating from ClearCase to Git and we are facing a problem when trying to clone the Git repositories we have created.

Repositories were created with a 1.9.x version of Git, but I'm trying to clone them with git version 2.9.2.windows.1. Apparently, the person who created the repositories manages to clone them with his old version of Git.

The errors I'm seeing are the following when running a git clone:

```
$ git clone /d/Users/T0111869/Desktop/migr_SRC/history/COM_CORE
Cloning into 'COM_CORE'...
done.
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
fatal: failed to read object b7ed8076ca4334f1d7337ac81a00d6fe7c2e793b: Invalid argument
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

If I try what is suggested by the error message, I get this:

```
$ git status
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
error: unable to unpack fb43c36b2de8ccab73a648a25ab5735406e1b595 header
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
fatal: loose object fb43c36b2de8ccab73a648a25ab5735406e1b595 (stored in .git/objects/fb/43c36b2de8ccab73a648a25ab5735406e1b595) is corrupt
```

and:

```
$ git checkout -f HEAD
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
error: unable to unpack fb43c36b2de8ccab73a648a25ab5735406e1b595 header
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
fatal: loose object fb43c36b2de8ccab73a648a25ab5735406e1b595 (stored in .git/objects/fb/43c36b2de8ccab73a648a25ab5735406e1b595) is corrupt
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to understand what's going on and how to overcome this problem ?

Thanks in advance
Nico

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/27806920/6309 help?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Error message is the same, doesn't give any information about which file is causing the problem (and the problem is general, as I have the same problem for each repository, just a different object file)

Comment: How about trying to do a bundle on the source computer, copy the bundle (one file), and clone from the bundle? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/40853323/6309)