# How to create a git repository backup with bundle where there is no linkage after cloning

Tags: git

Is there a way to create a backup using `git bundle` where there is no linkage to the bundle file after cloning from the backup? I'd like to backup my repositories to a single file with all history and restore them, exactly, later.

At the moment, I'm creating a backup using the following methodology:

```
$ mkdir here                  
$ cd here                                                                       
$ git init                                                                      
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/here/.git/                             
$ touch stuff                                                                   
$ git add stuff                                                                 
$ git commit -m "This is a file"                                                
[master (root-commit) c867bcf] This is a file                                   
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)                                
 create mode 100644 stuff                                                       
$ git bundle create myrepo.bundle --all                                         
Counting objects: 3, done.                                                      
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 212 bytes | 212.00 KiB/s, done.                    
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Alright, so at this point we have a bundle with a simple repository.  Now, when we try to copy this repository from the bundle:

```
$ cd ..
$ mkdir there                                                                   
$ cd there                                                                      
/tmp/there $ git clone ../here/myrepo.bundle .                                  
Cloning into '.'...                                                             
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.                                            
/tmp/there $ git remote -v                                                      
origin→ /tmp/there/../here/myrepo.bundle (fetch)                                
origin→ /tmp/there/../here/myrepo.bundle (push)
```

This shows that we have a link to the original bundle files, which I don't want.  I also tried to create a mirror, but the problem remains the same:

```
$ cd ..                                                                         
$ mkdir there                                                                   
$ cd there                                                                      
$ git clone --mirror ../here/myrepo.bundle ./.git                               
Cloning into bare repository './.git'...                                        
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.                                            
$ git config --bool core.bare false                                             
$ git reset --hard HEAD                                                         
HEAD is now at c867bcf This is a file                                           
/tmp/there $ git remote -v                                                      
origin→ /tmp/there/../here/myrepo.bundle (fetch)                                
origin→ /tmp/there/../here/myrepo.bundle (push)
```

Although we could just copy the entire repository as is to back things up, I really only want to backup a single file that only contains the files currently under revision.  I've been backing up the directories and it's been causing a mess with all of the leftover files.  As such, I'd really only like to archive a single file, which is why I'm using bundle, and I'd like the recovery from the backup to be clean as in no linkages at all to the bundle file.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not just do `git remote remove origin` after cloning?

Comment: @phd That sort of works except that when there are multiple branches they are also deleted since they're linked to origin.  I suppose that I could pull each of them and then delete origin, but that seems more clumsy that it should be unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The root of the problem is that you're using (misusing?) a transport mechanism (`git bundle`) as a backup mechanism. There's nothing inherently wrong with this, they just don't play well together, as you've discovered. You can paper over the "don't play well together" part, or use a real backup system, or whatever other solution you like. Note that the nature of a DVCS is that any one reop, once updated from another, is a superset of (if it has its own commits that the other doesn't), or is equal to, the other repo, so in some sense there's no need to make backups. But only in *some* sense.:-)

Comment: @torek I'll certainly admit that I may be misusing bundle.  However, if that's the case, is there a better way to backup a repository where we grab the full history of the repository and only backup the files under revision to a single file?

Comment: Not really, no—`git bundle` amounts to running `git fetch` or `git push` *without* the other (second) Git around to answer have/want queries, so the *git-rev-list-args* argument has to provide your best guesses about what they don't have (and hence want). Then the data stream that fetch or push would construct is instead made into a bundle-file. The result is that single file you'd like. You could make an archive of the `.git` directory with any archiver; that's probably similar enough if you always want everything, i.e., if your rev-list arguments are just `--all`.

Comment: The key differences would be that the archive would have archiver format (rather than `git bundle` format), would include ancillary data that `git bundle` might omit, and would include reflog-only objects that `--all` would omit. Oh, and the `.git` contents would include the index itself and `git add`-ed objects, plus the indexes and info for added worktrees (I guess these all could fall under "ancillary data").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of cloning from the bundle, create a new repository and fetch using a wildcard refspec. I have added a second branch `feature` and a tag `v1.0` to the example to make this more illustrative:

```
$ mkdir there
$ git init .
$ git fetch --update-head-ok ../here/myrepo.bundle '*:*'
Receiving objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From ../here/myrepo.bundle
 * [new tag]         v1.0       -> v1.0
 * [new branch]      master     -> master
 * [new branch]      feature    -> feature
$ git checkout
```

The `*:*` refspec will fetch all remote refs into equally named local refs, creating them if they don't exist. The `--update-head-ok` argument is needed since `git init` will create a `master` branch which is likely also present in the remote.

Since this is a fetch with a direct URL, no remotes are needed at all. Note that this would work equally for any kind of source repo URL, not just for bundles.

The equality of the refs of the old and new repository can be checked by comparing the output of `git show-ref` in both repositories, they should be identical.

Comment: I can also confirm that after using this trick and creating a new bundle of the new repository that it's identical to the original bundle.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This answer was very helpful to me, but there's a gap I'm trying to fill: The bundle was created from a bare repository, and I'm doing this `git fetch` of a bundle file also on a bare repository to later clone that bare repository. However, after fetching from the bundle, the bare repository's `HEAD` file still shows `refs/heads/master`, even though the bundle contains no `master` and `git bundle list-heads` shows `HEAD` pointing to `refs/heads/main`. How do I get the `HEAD` file correct after this fetch? (Can't use `git checkout` on a bare repository.)