# Getting all branches from git bundle

Tags: git

I've bundled a Git repository using `--all`, but I can't figure out how to get a repo back with all the branches.

How do I get all the branches back given a `.bundle` file?

Comment: If the goal is to restore a repo from a "backup bundle" then this may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371418

Comment: `git clone foo.bundle` didn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Note: if your intent was to create a new repository that has, in effect, been "restored from backup", you may want a different set of steps where you never create a remote at all. Setting that aside, here is the answer...)

1. Add (or use) the file as a (or the) remote, as described in [the `git bundle` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html#_example).  In the example in the documentation this happens automatically by using the bundle file as the source URL in a `git clone`, but you can use `git remote add`—see [the `git remote` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) for details—to add the bundle file as a new (additional, not-`origin`-named) remote to an existing repository.

   **Example command:** `git remote add myoldbundle path/to/myold.bundle`
2. Next you may want to edit the file `$GIT_DIR/config` to alter the behavior when `git fetch` reads the bundle.  This will work the same way as any `git fetch`, translating *their* branch names—stored in this bundle file being used as a remote—into *your* remote-tracking names by default.  This is due to that line documented in the `git bundle` manual:

   ```
   [remote "myoldbundle"]
           url = path/to/myold.bundle
           fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   ```

   (or similar), which tells `git fetch`: *Take their `refs/heads/*` names and produce `refs/remotes/origin/*` names.*

   If you change this set of directives, e.g., to read:

   ```
   fetch = refs/*:refs/*
   ```

   you will direct your Git to update (without forcing, in this case) *all* of your references to match *all* of their references, including tag names, `refs/notes/` references, and `refs/stash` if that exists.  This is similar to the configuration you get if you use `git clone --mirror`, which would set the `fetch` line to:

   ```
   fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
   ```

   Note the leading plus sign here, which means "force": overwrite *my* branch name (such as `refs/heads/master`) with *theirs*.  **This is only useful if you never do any work in the repository** since it will effectively destroy your branch hash IDs by overwriting them with theirs.  (You can retain the old hashes through reflogs, but that's rather tricky, and you will need to know how to deal with your index and work-tree becoming de-synchronized.)  **Note that a `--mirror` clone is automatically `--bare`, so that it has no work-tree, so that you cannot get yourself into trouble this way.**  Be careful if you use `+refs/*:refs/*`!
3. Finally use `git fetch` to read the file.

   **Example command:** `git fetch myoldbundle`

Comment: Ahh. . . so there is no way to simply replicate a repo.

Comment: `git clone` does replicate a repo, but with modifications along the way: replacing their branch names with your remote-tracking names (and dropping non-branch non-tag names entirely). `git clone --mirror` replicates but gives you a `--bare` repo, which you would then have to de-bare-ize. There's no built-in Git that does something in between, but since `git clone` is built out of six other commands, you can build your own.

Comment: This worked for me, but afterwards I had to fix the upstream back to origin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch