# Is it possible to bundle a git repo without making a local clone?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I want to bundle a Git repo which is hosted on Azure DevOps. I know from this question ([How to git bundle a complete repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792671/how-to-git-bundle-a-complete-repo)) how to do this but all examples I've seen start with making a local clone first.

I'm wondering if I can avoid this step and create a full bundle in a single step, directly from the online repository? If so, how?

Comment: Git works with local repositories. The very limited set of subcommands that work with remote repos is: `archive`, `ls-remote`, `clone`, `fetch`, `pull`, `push`, `remote`, that's all. If you have SSH access to the remote host you can run `git bundle` over SSH.

Comment: @phd seems a reasonable answer. The perfectionist in me feels that's messy - what if my local repo gets changed - but if that's how it works, then that's the answer :)