# Is there a way to transfer a GIT repo with history via file transfer

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

My company is letting a particular business go to another company. I have to get our GITHub source code repo into the new company's Azure DevOps Git repo. Problem is I keep getting authentication failed despite following every suggestion on the internet leading me to believe that it is something in the way the network is setup. Trying to find the right people to fix this is going to take way too long.

So, is it possible to git clone --mirror into a directory, zip that directory up, send it to the new company, and then have them remove and set the origin and push it into the repo?

Comment: Im not sure what your actual question is, honestly. A git repo is just a bunch of files, of course you can zip and unzip it, what makes you think you can't?

Comment: Technically a `.git` directory from any up-to-date clone will contain all history and a moderately skilled git user can bash it into shape. But the mirror clone seems best (has everything in local branches).

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [How to git bundle a complete repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11792671/11082165) and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle

Comment: You can remove the origin before you even send it.

Comment: Are you trying to do this simply because they can't figure out how to clone a private GitHub repo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to git bundle a complete repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792671/how-to-git-bundle-a-complete-repo)

Comment: @grg  similar, but not quite the same as this needs to move to a new origin.

Comment: Hi there, Glad to know the issue is resolved. Would you consider marking your answer? It may help others with similar concerns. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what @teapot418 in the comments answered, I went ahead and zipped up the git repo after removing the origin and adding the new origin. The new company was able to simply do

git push origin --all
git push --tags

and everything was there.

Answer (score 0):

- If you need to import the private GitHub Repo into Azure Repos, you can try to generate a `personal access token` for your GitHub Account as **basic** authentication during importing;
  [image]
  Select **Requires authorization** and enter the PAT;
  [image]
- If the private GitHub repo cannot be accessed using basic authentication, you can manually import a repository that uses SSH authentication by following the steps;

1. Generate SSH key pairs; by default the private and public keys are saved as `username/.ssh/id_rsa` and `username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

```
ssh-keygen
```

2. Add a new SSH key for your GitHub account with the value copied from the public key file `username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`;
   [image]
3. Create target **empty** repo in Azure DevOps and note the repo URL like `https://<AzureDevOpsOrgName>@dev.azure.com/<AzureDevOpsOrgName>/<TheProjectName>/_git/<TargetRepoName>`;
   [image]
4. Clone the source repo to a temporary folder on your computer using the `bare` option;

```
git clone --bare git@github.com:<TheGitHubOrg/AccountName>/<TheGitHubRepoName>.git
cd TheGitHubRepoName.git
```

5. Run the following command to copy the source repo to the target repo; Using `--mirror` will overwrite all branches in the target repo which includes deleting any branches not in the source repo; hence, it is suggested creating target Azure DevOps repo as an empty one.

```
git push --mirror https://<AzureDevOpsOrgName>@dev.azure.com/<AzureDevOpsOrgName>/<TheProjectName>/_git/<TargetRepoName>
```

- In addition, I tested to `clone` the GitHub repo onto the local directory;

```
git clone --mirror git@github.com:<TheGitHubOrg/AccountName>/<TheGitHubRepoName>.git
```

Archived all the contents as a `.zip` file and transferred it to another VM of mine; Having extracted the zip file on that machine, the `push` command also worked to push the commit history and branches from the local repo on that machine onto Azure Repos;

```
git push --mirror https://<AzureDevOpsOrgName>@dev.azure.com/<AzureDevOpsOrgName>/<TheProjectName>/_git/<TargetRepoName>
```

Hope the information would help.

Comment: Problem I run into is that it is currently in an enterprise GITHub repo that doesn't allow me to generate a PAT for myself. The security borders on not being able to get work done.